# Saving the new inputted data back to the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a page in rails which is pulling information from the database, I'm wanting to have it so that you can update the fields inside the DB. Heres the code i have so far. What happens so far is the ev.details is placed inside the text-angular editor, I'm wanting to have it so that when someone edits the text inside it and presses the submit changes button it would update the Details column with the data entered

Thanks

Controller:

```
  def update
    @events = Event.find_by_id(params[:id])

  end
```

Html.erb

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">
      <h3> Details </h3>
      <div text-angular ng-model="eventData.description"><%= raw(ev.details) %></div>
    </div>
    <div align="center">
    <button id="popover" data-content="Warning Changes can not be undone." rel="popover" data-placement="right" type="Submit" class="btn btn-danger">Submit Changes</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really should read an introduction to Ruby on Rails i.e. the [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html).

In a new Rails project, you can also try to run

```
rails generate scaffold Event details:text
```

and look at the generated code.